# how to add a MovieClip from the library by a class

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

how to add a MovieClip from the library by a class
i've  MovieClip  and i want to add it to the stage by a class

note 
i've already a class and linked to a MovieClip and what i woona do is to addChild another MovieClip in the stage

Comment: Could you perhaps be a little more specific?

Comment: i've already a class and linked to a MovieClip  and what i woona do is to addChild another MovieClip in the stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Library, you need to set your object Linkage Properties so that Export for Actionscript is checked and your library object has a class name. Then you should be able to call that class name in your code to add the library object to the stage

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html

Is this what you're after? basically two objects in the library and one of them adding the second as a child

```
var mc1:MovieClip = new MyClass();
var mc2:MovieClip = new MyClass2();
mc1.addChild( mc2 );
addChild(mc1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Library, right click on MovieClip, select Properties. In symbol Properties dialog: Check Export for ActionScript, and name it in the Class textbox. 
You can now treat it as regular ActionScript Class.

Let's say you named it: 'libraryMC'.

Instantiate Class and add it to the stage.

```
var myClip:libraryMC = new libraryMC();  // MovieClip instantiation
addChild(myClip); //actually adding instantiated MovieClip on the stage
```

Answer (score 0):

package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

```
public class FirstMOvieClip extends MovieClip {

    public function FirstMOvieClip () {

        addChild (new SecondMovieClip())
                    // This will add second MovieClip to first MovieClip 
    }
```

}

You can not add second movie-clip to stage unless first movie-clip is added to stage. This is what i think, you were asking.